# add a function as the value of a parameter into another function in powershell

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have this simple code to test the path of the log file

```
function logfile{
$LOGFILEpfad = 'C:\Temptest'
if((Test-Path -path $LOGFILEpfad) -eq $false) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\' -Name 'Temptest'
} 

$LOGFILEnamecheck = (gci -Path "C:\TEMPtest"  | ?{$_.Name -eq 'PingLog.txt'} | select name).name
if($LOGFILEnamecheck -ne 'PingLog.txt' ) {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $LOGFILEpfad -Name 'PingLog.txt'
}
return "$LOGFILEpfad\$LOGFILEnamecheck"
```

}

this function is going to return the full path of the log file that is created.

How can I pass this path into another function? I can't do it like below

```
function Test($LOGFILEpath = logfile) {
CODE....
```

}

I don't want to invoke the logfile function and save the value into another variable and then give it that as a fixed value of the $LOGFILEpath parameter of the Test Function.

Does anyone have an idea?